# NameError for variable assigned in exec, although it exists in locals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, eval, nameerror

When I run the code below, I get a `NameError`:

```
def foo():
    exec("data = [1, 2, 3]", globals(), locals())
    return data

foo()  # Returns an error:
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-24-617677c4ff0e> in <module>()
#       3     return data
#       4
# ----> 5 foo()
# 
# <ipython-input-24-617677c4ff0e> in foo()
#       1 def foo():
#       2     exec("data = [1, 2, 3]")
# ----> 3     return data
#       4
#       5 foo()
# 
# NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Even though the assignment seemed to work, and I can return it by manually indexing into the locals-namespace:

```
def bar():
    exec("data = [1, 2, 3]")
    return vars()["data"]

bar()  # Returns [1, 2, 3]
```

How come?

Comment: funny, the code works under python 2